# Pandas groupby Increment datetime to make it unique for the group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe which looks something like below:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'State': ['Texas', 'Texas', 'Florida', 'Florida'],
                       'a': [4, 5, 1, 3], 'b': [6, 10, 3, 11]})
    df['ts'] = datetime.utcnow()
```

table looks something  like this below

```
     State  a   b                ts
0    Texas  4   6 2022-09-06 15:33:31
1    Texas  5  10 2022-09-06 15:33:31
2  Florida  1   3 2022-09-06 15:33:31
3  Florida  3  11 2022-09-06 15:33:31
```

what I want to achieve, is for each group 'ts' should be unique, so I want to increment it's all other values with +1 second
so the output dataframe will look like this:

```
     State  a   b                ts
0    Texas  4   6 2022-09-06 15:33:31
1    Texas  5  10 2022-09-06 15:33:32
2  Florida  1   3 2022-09-06 15:33:31
3  Florida  3  11 2022-09-06 15:33:32
```

With groupby and transform, able to get the series, but can't get any further:

```
df['ts'] = df['ts'].groupby(df['State']).transform(lambda x: increment_ms(x))
```

How can I achieve the above output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby().cumcount()` with `pd.to_timedelta`:

```
df['ts'] += pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby('State').cumcount(), unit='s')
```

Output:

```
     State  a   b                         ts
0    Texas  4   6 2022-09-06 15:40:46.429416
1    Texas  5  10 2022-09-06 15:40:47.429416
2  Florida  1   3 2022-09-06 15:40:46.429416
3  Florida  3  11 2022-09-06 15:40:47.429416
```

Comment: i checked cumsum, didn't knew about cumcount thanks works like charm, answer accepted with gratitude